# I am getting undefined in JavaScript and can't figure it out why

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, foreach

I am trying out a simple program that outputs to console. Everything works fine just getting unexpected undefined and I don't know why I am getting it. Anybody please explain whats wrong and how can I make my code better. Thanks

```js
var next = document.getElementById('next');

var questions = 
[

    {
      question: "Color of sky is ?",
      choices: ["Green","White", "Blue", "Red"],
      answer: 2
    },
    {
      question: "Color of milk is ?",
      choices: ["Green","White", "Blue", "Red"],
      answer: 1
    },
    {
      question: "Color of Grass is ?",
      choices: ["Green","White", "Blue", "Red"],
      answer: 0
    }

];

var counter = 0;


function loadQuestion () {
 
  var obj = questions[counter];
  var quest = obj.question;
  var choice = obj.choices;
  function options() {
    choice.forEach(function(val){
     
      console.log(val);
      return false;
    });
  }
  var answer = obj.answer;
  
  counter++;
  
  console.log ( " Question : " + quest );
  console.log( options() );
  console.log( answer );
}

next.onclick = function() {
  if ( counter < questions.length ) {
  loadQuestion();
  }
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="quiz-container">
    <button id="next"> Next Question </button>
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: console.log( options() ) does not work. Try just options() and remove the return false in the options function

Comment: thanks @Jonas w it works now.

Comment: can you please guide me how can I create readio buttons with options function values ?

Comment: Open another question -> getting another answer

Answer (score 2):

Why you do:

```
console.log( options() );
```

in `options` function you already print the options so you should replace this line with only:

```
options();
```

and if you are wondering why its print `undefined` because `options` function is return nothing(return false is only the return for forEach callback for each item), if you do the following it will print `true` instead of `undefined`:

```
function options() {
  choice.forEach(function(val){

   console.log(val);
   return false;
  });
  return true;
}
```

Example:

```
function a(){}
console.log( a() ); //undefined

function a(){return 1;}
console.log( a() ); // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Like everyone said, you can not console.log a function. Just run the `options()` after printing the questions like this

```
---snip---
console.log('Question: ' + quest);
options(); // print options
console.log('Answer: ' + answer);
---snip---
```

There are many ways to generate radio buttons from your list of choices. I have provided one way I like to use, below.

I have assumed that there is a `button element inside your form

```
--- snip ---
function generateQuestion(parent, question) {
    var h3_ = document.createElement('h3');
    var question_ = document.createTextNode(question);
    h3_.appendChild(question_);
    parent.insertBefore(h3_, parent.firstChild);
}

function generateOptions(parent,options) {

    options.forEach(function(val){
        parent.insertBefore(
          makeSpan(makeRadioButtons('choice',val), val),
          parent.firstChild // the button element
        );
    });
}

function makeRadioButtons(name_, value_) {
    var radio_b = document.createElement("input");
    radio_b.setAttribute('type','radio');
    radio_b.setAttribute('name',name_);
    radio_b.setAttribute('value',value_);
    return radio_b;
}

function makeSpan(radio_button, value) {
    var span_ = document.createElement('span');
    var text_ = document.createTextNode(value);
    span_.appendChild(radio_button);
    span_.appendChild(text_);
    return span_;
}

//get my form
var my_form = document.getElementById('my_form');

function loadQuestion() {
    ---snip---
    generateOptions(my_form, choice);
    generateQuestion(my_form, quest);
    ---snip---
}
```

There are more ways using string, but I find those hard to maintain later on.
Here is the working example of the code provided above: https://jsfiddle.net/04hruhyo/